# When is hdfs-site.xml loaded by hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I have hive and hadoop installed in my system.

This is my hdfs-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

If i do bin/start-all.sh and go to my hive and run a select query I get the error  :

```
The ratio of reported blocks 0.0000 has not reached the threshold 0.9990. Safe mode will be turned off automatically.
```

If I wait for some time and run the hive query again, it works.

I read that the safemode threshold is set using the property: **dfs.namenode.safemode.threshold-pct**

I added that property in my hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.safemode.threshold-pct</name>
     <value>0.500f</value>
</property>
```

Again i started all hadoop nodes, and run the hive query, But i was still getting the same error

```
The ratio of reported blocks 0.0000 has not reached the threshold 0.9990. Safe mode will
```

It means that either my xml is wrong, or I have to do something else to actually load the hdfs-site.xml.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you restarted hadoop after making the change.

Comment: How many data nodes do you have in your cluster?

Comment: Ya I have restarted. I am running in pseudo distributed mode with 1 data node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing a mistake. I went a checked the hdfs-default.xml in the src folder and found this

```
<property>
<name>dfs.safemode.threshold.pct</name>
<value>0.999f</value>
<description>
Specifies the percentage of blocks that should satisfy 
the minimal replication requirement defined by dfs.replication.min.
Values less than or equal to 0 mean not to start in safe mode.
Values greater than 1 will make safe mode permanent.
</description>
</property>
```

I think i am using old version of hadoop because dfs.safemode.threshold.pct is deprecatd.

Modified my hdfs-site.xml,stopped and started the namenode

```
<property>
<name>dfs.safemode.threshold.pct</name>
<value>2</value>
</property>
```

and it worked!

```
The ratio of reported blocks 0.0000 has not reached the threshold 2.0000. Safe mode will be turned off automatically.
```